# Get the query plan using jdbc PreparedStatement on sql server

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, prepared-statement

Using Statment, resultSet.getObject returns query plan as xml

```
 Connection conn = getConnection();
        String query = " SET SHOWPLAN_XML on ";
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        boolean execute=st.execute(query);
        log.info("execute status {} " , execute);
         query = " SELECT ATMPROFILES.TERMID as COLUMNID, ATMPROFILES.TERMID as COLUMNNAME FROM ATMPROFILES (NOLOCK) "
                + " WHERE Authprocessname = 'ATMST' "
                + "ORDER BY ATMPROFILES.TERMID ";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            Object object = rs.getObject(1);
            log.info("Query Plan {}  ", object);
        }
```

But If I execute the same through PreparedStatement, it returns actual result insteadof QueryPlan

```
 Connection conn = getConnection();
        String query = " SET SHOWPLAN_XML on ";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        boolean execute = ps.execute();
        log.info("execute status {} " , execute);

         query = " SELECT ATMPROFILES.TERMID as COLUMNID, ATMPROFILES.TERMID as COLUMNNAME FROM ATMPROFILES (NOLOCK) "
                + " WHERE Authprocessname = 'ATMST' "
                + "ORDER BY ATMPROFILES.TERMID ";
        ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
        execute=ps.execute();
        log.info("execute status {} " , execute);
        ResultSet rs = ps.getResultSet();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            Object object = rs.getObject(1);
             // here it returns selected object
            log.info("Query Plan {}  ", object); 

        }
```

Any idea to acheive this via PreparedStatement.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any reference why executing `SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON` as a prepared statement will not work; however, you should get the desired results when you run this statement directly and your actual query as a prepared statement. In code:

```
Connection conn = getConnection();
String showplanQuery = "SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON";
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
st.execute(showplanQuery);

String actualQuery = "SELECT ATMPROFILES.TERMID FROM ATMPROFILES (NOLOCK) ";
PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(actualQuery);
ps.execute();
ResultSet rs = ps.getResultSet();
while(rs.next())
{
    Object object = rs.getObject(1);
    // should log the query plan
    log.info("Query Plan {}  ", object); 
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried this eariler, didnt work. Result set is  Null for `ps.getResultSet();`

Comment: @vels4j: Which SQL Server version and JDBC driver are you using? I tried at home with SQL Server 2012, jTDS 1.3.1, and a table different from yours; however, I didn't expect these differences to matter much. The `ps.getResultSet()` in my example was not `null`, then.

Comment: using sqljdbc4-4.0.2206.100.jar via maven