# Retrieve query execution plan text from a MSSQL server using JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have the following Java method that is only returning the statement itself. How can I retrieve the MSSQL query execution plan text using JDBC?

```
 public String explainStatementMssql(String sqlStatement) {
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    try {
      connection = Utilities.getConnection();
      connection.setAutoCommit(false);
      statement = connection.createStatement();
      statement.execute("SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON");
      statement.executeQuery(sqlStatement);
      rs = statement.getResultSet();
      while (rs.next()) {
        output.append(rs.getString(1)).append("\n");
      }
      statement.execute("SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT OFF");
      connection.commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
      Utilities.close(rs, statement, connection);
    }
    return output.toString();
  }
```

Environment: `java -version`

```
java version "1.7.0_101"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.6) (7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
jtds-1.2.6.jar
Microsoft SQL Server 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the first example in the following post:
[Get the query plan using jdbc PreparedStatement on sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187846/get-the-query-plan-using-jdbc-preparedstatement-on-sql-server)

It's not using jtds, but I'm sure minor tweaks should provide you with what you're looking for.