# Unable to obtain SQL execution plan in Java for Prepared- and CallableStatement with sqljdbc4.jar

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

We have recently implemented Microsoft Type 4 JDBC Driver (sqljdbc4.jar of Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.2 for SQL Server)in favor of jTDS. We are now having problems when trying to retrieve estimated- and actual execution plans for both Callable- and PreparedStatement objects from within our Java code.
The only lead I've been able to locate is:
[Get the query plan using jdbc PreparedStatement on sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187846/get-the-query-plan-using-jdbc-preparedstatement-on-sql-server)
but no concrete answer have been provided yet.
The database is SQL Server 2008R2.
Example code is:

```
Connection cn          = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
Statement execplan_stmt = null;
ResultSet rs           = null;
try
{
    cn = getConnection();

    execplan_stmt = cn.createStatement();
    execplan_stmt.executeUpdate("SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON");
    stmt = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT value FROM cfg_system_properties WHERE 
                                property = ?"); 
    stmt.execute();
    rs = stmt.getResultSet();
    while(rs != null && rs.next())
    {
        Object obj = rs.getObject(1);
        System.out.println("Query plan {} " + obj);
   }
   execplan_stmt.execute("SET SHOWPLAN_XML OFF");          

}
catch (SQLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Even replacing the

```
while(rs != null && rs.next())
```

loop statement with

```
if(rs.next())
{
    String exec_plan = rs.getString(1);
}
```

does not work, as rs.next() is false. 
In this example the sql contains a placeholder character '?', which firstly causes a "java.sql.SQLException: Parameter #1 has not been set." error, which is unwanted. I do not want to execute the query, I want to obtain the execution plan, be it the actual or estimated query plan.
Replacing the placeholder with an actual value doesn't break it anymore, but no execution plan is returned.
Activating SQL profiler indicates a execution plan should be returned, but as the linked article correctly states, it appears that the actual result is returned and not the execution plan. 
Is the driver perhaps throwing the execution plan away?
Are there any specific configurations required to be set when obtaining the database connection that need to be set in order to be able to do this?
Has anybody successfully done this?

Comment: where do you add the db config params? and catch the general exception well..

Comment: You never bind a Parameter to the placeholder

Comment: are you aware of the proper way to create a sql query with java ? as @Jens mentions , you do not apply a certain value to the placeholder ........

Comment: The db config parameters is hidden in getConnection(). For obvious reasons I'm not at liberty to provide company configuration details on this public forum. As for not binding a proper value to the placeholder, the intention is not to execute the query, but to retrieve and obtain the estimated or actual query execution plan. Thus I do not require the query to actually be executed. Executing the commands in SQL Server Manager works. I am just unable to figure out how to successfully do this in Java.

Comment: I have learned that to obtain the Estimated Execution Plan you need to specify the "SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON" argument to the Statement.executeUpdate(), and that the placeholder parameter needs to be enclosed in single quotes in order for the code to execute successfully. The problem still is that the rs.next() is false, even though if you execute rs.getMetaData().getColumnname(1) it contains the value "Microsoft SQL Server 2005 XML Showplan".  So the problem still is, how to obtain the estimated execution plan?

Comment: Specifying Statement.executeUpdate("SET STATISTICS XML ON") is used to obtain the actual execution plan (and then the parameter placeholder is not in singe quotes and you set it with a value), but the result of rs.getObject(1) is the actual response value, and not the actual execution plan. The value for rs.getMetaData().getColumnname(1) is also the column name value, and not indicative that a execution plan is contained.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not return estimated execution plans for the execution of prepared statements. jTDS has a quirk with executes Java PreparedStatement’s more like plain Statement’s causing SQL Server to return an estimated execution plan. The MS driver does not have this quirk and so no estimated execution plan is ever returned when executing a Java Prepared- or CallableStatement. When using jTDS, the estimated execution plan might be returned, but it isn’t guaranteed for all PreparedStatement’s.